# How to count value in pandas dataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Like `df.isnull().sum()` for counting Nan value, I m looking to count another value : `'MISSED'`.

Does anybody know if there is any build-in fonction in pandas to do that, or how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) for numpy boolen array and `sum` all `True`s:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                   'B':[4,5,4,5,5,'missed'],
                   'C':['missed',8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':['missed',3,6,9,2,'missed'],
                   'F':list('aaabbb')})

print (df)
   A       B       C  D       E  F
0  a       4  missed  1  missed  a
1  b       5       8  3       3  a
2  c       4       9  5       6  a
3  d       5       4  7       9  b
4  e       5       2  1       2  b
5  f  missed       3  0  missed  b

count = (df.values == 'missed').sum()
print (count)
4
```

Comment: @StefanFalk - it is [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) - convert to `numpy array`

Comment: Just `(df == 'missed').sum()` also works fine.  `(df == 'missed').sum().sum()` if we want the total `missed` of the whole dataframe.

Comment: when i use {.isnull().sum()}, that return a pandas Series : column / count 
but when i use {values} i have juste the general sum (int64)

Comment: @b0chData - Then use `count = (df.astype(str)== 'missed').sum()`

Comment: exactly what i want thank you